# al momento de crear un archivo con rails y webpack me genera un error al momento de insertar

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vue.js, webpack

cree un archivo con rails y webpack:

```
rails new myapp --webpack=vue
```

y me crea un folder dentro de rails:

```
app/javascript
└── packs
    ├── app.vue
    └── hello_vue.js
```

app.vue:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <ul v-for="result in results">
      <li>{{result.name}}</li>
    </ul>
    <!-- <p>{{ results.name}}</p> -->
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data: {
    results: []
  },
  mounted(){
    axios.get("xxxxx")
    .then(response => {
      this.results = response.data
    })
  }
}
</script>
```

hello_vue.js:

```
    import Vue from 'vue'
    import App from './app.vue'

    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
      document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('hello'))
      const app = new Vue(App).$mount('hello')

      console.log(app)
    })

y lo agrego dentro de la vista de esta forma:

    <%= javascript_pack_tag 'hello_vue' %>
```

pero cuando quiero crear un nuevo archivo dentro de packs me genera un error al momento de agregar lo en la vistas, solo me funciona si creo archivo copia de los originales con un numero ejemplo:

hello2_vue

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App2 from './app2.vue'

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('hello2'))
  const app2 = new Vue(App2).$mount('hello2')

  console.log(app2)
})
```

app2:

```
<template>
  <div id="app2">
    <ul v-for="result in results">
      <li>{{result.name}}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  data: {
    results: []
  },
  mounted(){
    axios.get("xxxxxxxxxxxx")
    .then(response => {
      this.results = response.data
    })
  }
}
</script>
```

alguna idea de que puede estar generando este error?????

Comment: ...¿y cual sería el error?

Comment: No me permite crear otro archivo que no sea con el mismo nombre que el original (app.js y hello_vue), ya que he intentado crear otros con el nombre de menu.js y menu_vue, pero no los reconoce me manda un error de ruta